# svg radialGradient stop-opacity not animatable?

Tags: jquery, svg, radial-gradients

I want to animate the stop-opacity of a gradient in an svg element using jQuery, but it doesn't work. Animating stop-color, however, does work using the same code.

HTML:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:white;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:white;stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#someelement').on('click', function(){
  $('stop:eq(1)').css('stop-opacity',1);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is stop-opacity simply not-animatable?

UPDATE I

According to W3, stop-opacity *is* animatable. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#GradientStops

Comment: That link means it's SMIL animatable. That's not what you're doing, although having said that what you're doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the value of stop-opacity is a string, not an integer.

If I change the jQuery to .css('stop-opacity','1') - it works.

Strange, though.